# Is there a difference between "Etc/UTC" and "UTC" in logstash?

Tags: iis, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Im parsing W3C IIS logs and I'm using what I found in [this article](https://blog.sstorie.com/importing-iis-logs-into-elasticsearch-with-logstash/) as a starter.

But this part of his logstash config Im unsure of:

```
  ## Set the Event Timesteamp from the log
  #
  date {
    match => [ "log_timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      timezone => "Etc/UTC"
  }
```

log_timestamp comes from: `match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}.....`

My question is why is he using "Etc/UTC" and not just "UTC"? This is the only example I could find online of a logstash config using "Etc/UTC".

Is this necessary because of IIS? What would happen if I just did UTC? They should be identical (etc/UTC just the "long" name) but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported timezones for the `date` filter are listed here:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

`Etc/UTC` is one of the allowed timezones for Universal Time Coordinated. `UTC` is also an allowed value. They're synonyms.